# Proxying certains URL's to another server, while also keeping request to original server

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

I need to receive a request to my webserver and then spawn "a copy" of the http request to another server. Both servers need to receive this request. For instance:

When serverA.com/dosomething is hit, automatically the serverB.com/differentUrl is also hit, with the exact same request. Well... I suppose the "location" header would be different.

Can I do this directly in Apache? How?

Comment: Please explain further why you want to do this? The browser or other client software won't be able to deal with two responses from different machines.

Comment: I don't want two responses. I only want that serverB be notified of the request, there's no need for serverA to know the response sent by serverB. For now I'm using a PHP script to do it.

Comment: If ServerB is a web server, it's going to be responding to that request. I'm going to ask again - what problem are you trying to solve? Why doesn't good URL logging accomplish your goal, for example?

Comment: It's going to respond to ServerB, not to the original request made by the client. The problem is the following: I have a legacy webserver that receives payment status notifications. We are implementing a new webserver that also needs to receive these notifications, but I can only have one webserver receiving them. So ServerA receives it, do what it needs to do and calls ServerB to also do what it needs to do.